# How do I run flask on codebox IDE?

Tags: python, flask

When I create a Python box, I run command `pip install -r requirements.txt` then I click the Run button on the side and I can see the existing app run.

What exactly is happening when Run is clicked?

I've updated the existing file **app.py**, I made `def hello():` return something new, however, it seems like codebox does not update and I still see hello world.

What is happening when I click on the Run button? I'm trying to follow the Mega Flask Tutorial but haven't been able to make the flask server return the correct value, it always returns "hello world".

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is happening when Run is clicked?

It run the `app.py` on the codebox vm.
It maybe `python app.py`

To update, you fist should save your change(`ctrl-s`), and stop the run app, run it again.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's running app.py because I've changed the port on which that flask app runs and it still shows it's running on port 2000. Also, I tried running my app from the terminal and discovered I can click on Projects>Ports>5000 but even then, "Hello world" still shows up instead of what my view function returns.